How do I inject a collection of beans with Dagger -- without explicitly declaring a collection as a bean?
Suppose I want to inject a map of keys to matching instances. With Spring, I could do it very easily
@Bean
// injecting a collection of all beans matching the MyDomainObject type
public Map<String, MyDomainObject> map(List<MyDomainObject> objects) {
    Map<String, MyDomainObject> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (MyDomainObject object : objects) {
        map.put(object.getKey(), object);
    }
    return map;
}

It's very flexible. If MyDomainObject is an abstract type, I can simply declare new implementations (for example, writing new MyDomainObjectImpls and marking them as @Components), and the map bean method will 1) automatically pick up new beans while 2) keeping its signature
I am hard-pressed to achieve the same with Dagger (which I have to switch to since I'm now doing frontend, still in Java)
How can I do a similar thing in Dagger?
ChatGPT suggested this
@Module
public abstract class TypeModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    abstract Type provideType1(TypeImpl1 typeImpl1);

    @Binds
    @IntoSet
    abstract Type provideType2(TypeImpl2 typeImpl2);

    // Add more @Binds methods for other Type implementations
}

Do I really have to create a new bean declaration for each new implementation and mark it with @Into(List/Set...)?
